# I can't get Docker containers to access the internet?

Tags: networking, docker

I'm my wits end with this, I've combed every single google result and nothing helps.

I'm completely unable to get docker containers to access the internet. IP forwarding is enabled (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`), ufw is turned off, I've tried adding the `-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4` flags. Every possible solution I've ever found on google fails.

Anyone have any idea how to help?

Attempting to reset everything, as recommend [here](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300) causes the entire thing to break by telling me that `docker -d` isn't running even though it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolved. I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1809): commented out `dns=dnsmasq` line in `NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: This answer is better because it also fixes `docker build`.

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 16+, the command to restart the network manager is now `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` because it's using `systemd` instead of `upstart`.

Comment: Tried all tricks but it keeps shown '0% [Connecting to 120.0.0.1 (120.0.0.1)] [Connecting to 120.0.0.1 (120.0.0.1)]'.  Any idea how to fix this?  I have the container running in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 32):

I was facing the same problem. So, to solve that issue I've started the container using the argument `--net=host`, it worked perfectly for me.

Here goes the full statement

```
sudo docker start --net=host -it --name ex_ngninx ubuntu
```

Comment: This made it temporarily work but I still couldn't `docker build`.  A `sudo systemctl restart docker` fixed it tho

Comment: This is kind of a dubious 'fix'. It's a workaround at best.

Comment: I have been googling for a while and `--net=host` saved me

Comment: `--net host` on [Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac) allows the containers access to the internet, but [disables host access to the containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos).  Defining a [network in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) worked for me.

Comment: `--net` is not a `docker build` option but `--network` seems to be a valid alias for it